# MYSQL - Simple after insert trigger won't fire

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Here I have the following trigger:

```
USE dbsspf;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER TR_ASSIGN_PAGEINDEX
AFTER INSERT
ON LIB_RECORDS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  UPDATE LIB_RECORDS
  SET
  PAGE_INDEX = 13;


END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see I'm just updating the table in my trigger. However when I insert a new record the trigger does not fire. Can you please show me what I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *B.5.9: Can triggers access tables?*
>
> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger
>   can also affect other tables, but it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9

In other words, a trigger on `LIB_RECORDS` cannot write other rows on `LIB_RECORDS`.

Comment: Thanks for very important info. What whould then you suggest me to do in this case?

Comment: No, what I need is exactly what I tried to achieve in my trigger. I need to change the PAGE_INDEX column of all the records of the same table that a new record is being inserted into.

Comment: ... change it to `13`. That's same as making a read-only `NOT NULL DEFAULT 13` column, isn't it?

Comment: But it's not always 13. It'll be different depending on the number of records in the table.